# Changing cluster radius based on point count

Tags: javascript, mapbox, mapbox-gl

I'm using this example to cluster mapbox points: https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/cluster/

I wish I could use {point_count} as the circle-radius property but I'm unsure how to use it properly. Is something like that possible? Are there variables in an object somewhere that I can access somewhere?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

check this awesome [data-driven-styling](https://www.mapbox.com/blog/data-driven-styling/)

replace the circle-radius with below(maybe need latest mapbox-gl-js)

```
    'circle-radius': 
    {
     property: "point_count",
     stops: [
         [0,   10],
         [50, 20],
         [100,   30]
          ]
   }
```

[image]

Comment: Excellent! Thank you.